# how to use variable as DEFINE value in php

Tags: php, constants

**This works when I hardcode value for constant:**

```
define("SERVER","localhost");
 define("USER","root");
 define("PASSWORD","mypass");
 define("DATABASE","my_db");
 define("PORT","3306");
```

But I have to get value from variable but this doesn't work:

```
define("SERVER",$host);
 define("USER",$username);
 define("PASSWORD",$password);
 define("DATABASE",$database);
 define("PORT","3306");


$conn = new connection(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,PORT);
```

> I searched online, even PHP manual doesn't show example for constant
>   with variable's value. For my app I have to get it from variable, how
>   to get this right?

I'm getting error like this:

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\wamp\www\ezy\class.dbconnect.php on line 33
```

**Full code for config.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
//read for config details  
$myFile = "details.txt";
$lines = file($myFile);

$host = $lines[0];//localhost
$username = $lines[1];//root
$password = $lines[2];//mypass
$org_name = $lines[3];//zealous
$database = $lines[4];//zealous_db

//include files starts
include('class.dbconnect.php');
//include files ends

//db credentials localhost

 define("SERVER",$host);
 define("USER",$username);
 define("PASSWORD",$password);
 define("DATABASE",$database);
 define("PORT","3306");

 $conn = new connection(SERVER,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE,PORT);

?>
```

**class dbconnect.php**

```
<?php
interface db
{
    public function __construct($param,$param2,$param3,$param4,$param5);
}
abstract class connectionStatus
{
    public function connectionStatus()
    {
        echo "Connection Established!";
    }
}
class connection extends connectionStatus implements db 
{
    public static $server;
    public static $user;
    public static $pass;
    public static $dbname;
    public static $port;    
    public static $pdo;


    public  function __construct($param,$param2,$param3,$param4,$param5)
    {
      self::$server = $param;
      self::$user = $param2;
      self::$pass = $param3;
      self::$dbname = $param4;
      self::$port = $param5;

      try 
      {
          self::$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.self::$server.'; dbname='.self::$dbname, self::$user, self::$pass);
          self::$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      } catch(PDOException $e)
      {
          echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
      }

      self::$pdo->query("use ".self::$dbname);
      //$this->connectionStatus();

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: if you didn't assign anything to those variables, then that's the problem. You should now be getting undefined variable notices.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I did but din't show in the code above, and tested to echo them  and they work

Comment: you need to show us the rest of your PDO connection code then and how they're used exactly. This is guesswork right now.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I just need to know one thing: which is can I use variable for DEFINE or not. If can how else what's the alternative.

Comment: I still don't see where you've assigned anything to those variables. You can't assign a constant to a variable that hasn't yet been assigned.

Comment: before define("SERVER",$host); you must assign $host = "localhost"; ?

Comment: ^ what do you think I said already, and twice @SonuR

Comment: `$lines = file($myFile);` -> `$lines = file($myFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);` (+ You may want to return your connection, otherwise your assignment to `$conn` doesn't make much sense)

Comment: @Rizier123, why must ignore the lines, I'm making use of them

Comment: @Fred-ii-, above I updated the full code, so you know how I'm getting the values for the variable?

Comment: @Keren Because your host won't be `localhost`, but `localhost\n`

Comment: @SonuR, refer to my code above

Comment: Why would you want to define variable as a constant? Constant gets defined once and it stays the same ever since. Now you first define a variable that gets turned into constant. It seems a bit funny approach (you have two steps where one would be sufficient). Sorry for not helping, the logic just seems odd to me.

Comment: another thing besides what @Rizier123 said. If your text file contains spaces after each line besides the hidden `\n`'s, then that will also fail in the DSN. I also hope you protected that file in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to create `define`'s why not just do

```
<?php
session_start();

//read for config details  
$lines = file("details.txt");

include('class.dbconnect.php');

$conn = new connection(trim($lines[0]),
                       trim($lines[1]),
                       trim($lines[2]),
                       trim($lines[4]),
                       '3306'
                      );
?>
```

I am not saying its a great idea, but what is the point of creating DEFINE() when there is no need

Personally I would be tempted to add all these values you get from a file to the `class.dbconnect.php` class as private properties. Keeping them in a text file is pretty much like keeping them in a `.php` file.
At least `.php` files are automatically protected by a web server, where `.txt` files are not unless you do something to make them protected

Comment: Folly, I agree with you, these credentials are supposed to be private, I'm just studying on writing and reading from txt file.Thanks a lot your answer works

Comment: Nice use of `trim()` there Smokey. Unsure if the OP's file does contain spaces but always best to be ahead of the game ;-)

Comment: Thanks Ralph, got to admit I half borrowed the bit about protection from your comment. I was going to put something like that in the answer, decided it might be overkill, but when I saw you comment thought I would go back and add it. @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly You were more than welcome to use it Smokey ;-) *You know that*.